# Extrapolating from a smooth monotonic curve in R

Tags: r, regression, extrapolation

I am trying to extrapolate a smooth monotonic curve made with `scam()`. Please see the following code and produced images:

```r
library(scam)
library(mgcv)
library(nlme)
library(ggplot2)

DF <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(15548, 16149, 16513, 
     16858,  17211, 17617, 17985), class = "numeric"), 
      percentile = c(1.90982475506864, 2.94546018485894, 
      3.00516383648267, 2.96295221921635, 3.7070240276891, 
      6.52469881377116, 7.70470323658277)), row.names = c(NA, 
      -7L), class = "data.frame")

    # Fit  monotonically increasing convex spline
    scam.model <- scam(percentile ~ s(Date, k = 4, bs = 'micx'), 
      data = DF)

    # Missing an intercept perhaps? 
    plot(scam.model); points(as.numeric(DF$Date), DF$percentile, 
    col = 'red')

# Fit as expected
ggplot(DF, mapping = aes(Date,percentile)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'scam',
              formula = y ~ s(x, k = 4, bs = 'micx'),
              se = T)
```

[image: base]
[image: ggplot]

My questions are the following:

1. Why is there a difference in the two plots? Does `geom_smooth()` somehow force the intercept by any chance?
2. Is it possible to determine the value of `Date` for which `percentile` would surpass a threshold? The other way around would be easier with some `predict()` function I assume, but for my use I am interested in this direction.
3. Would you recommend another techniques and packages for this kind of extrapolation?

Answer (score 2):

I think I can only answer 2.

Create a new data frame containing many Date values within the range of your data and add the predicted values from your model.

```
newdata <- data.frame(Date=seq(min(DF$Date), max(DF$Date), by=1))
newdata$pr <- predict.scam(scam.model, newdata = newdata)
```

You seek the value of `Date` for which `percentile` would exceed a certain threshold. Let's say this threshold is 4.

```
newdata[which.max(newdata$pr>4),]
#       Date      pr
# 1544 17091 4.00036
```

[image]

Comment: I see, clever solution! However, not to undermine your answer, I was hoping to find a more explicit way of finding the threshold rather than predicting for several values for `Date`. This would still work in my case though, so thank you.

Comment: Those gam/scam models always tie me up in knots; I can never figure out the closed-form formula. So I just let the computer figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can only answer 1

When you do `plot(scam.model)`, it is in fact `plot.scam(scam.model)` and in the [source code of plot.scam](https://rdrr.io/cran/scam/src/R/plot.r), it chooses to omit the intercept and use only your other coefficients. This is the relevant lines:

```
if (m>0) for (i in 1:m) { ## work through smooth terms
    first <- x$smooth[[i]]$first.para
    last <- x$smooth[[i]]$last.para
```

I guess it is meant for comparisons with other models, and you might have to read it in more detail. So to get the values fitted, you can do:

```
plot(scam.model,shift=scam.model$coefficients[1,])
points(as.numeric(DF$Date), DF$percentile, col = 'red')
```

[image]

And to answer your questions:

> 1. Why is there a difference in the two plots? Does geom_smooth()
>      somehow force the intercept by any chance?

geom_smooth() takes the fitted values from scam.model. The fit is the same. The difference you see comes from plot.scam having a different choice of plotting.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! It still makes me wonder why their base `plot()` function would not simply plot the fit. For comparing with other models I would look at the coefficients explicitly. Regardless, thank you for taking the time to check in the code.